# How to Access string in file by position in Java

Tags: java, file

I have a text file with the following contents:

```
one
two
three
four
```

I want to access the string "three" by its position in the text file in Java.I found the substring concept on google but unable to use it.

so far I am able to read the file contents:

```
import java.io.*;
class FileRead 
{
 public static void main(String args[])
  {
  try{
  // Open the file that is the first 
  // command line parameter
  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
  // Get the object of DataInputStream
  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  String strLine;
  //Read File Line By Line
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  // Print the content on the console
  System.out.println (strLine);
  }
  //Close the input stream
  in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  }
```

}

I want to apply the substring concept to the file.It asks for the position and displays the string.

```
 String Str = new String("Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com");
 System.out.println(Str.substring(10, 15) );
```

Comment: Please do not wrap a DataInputStream with a Reader.  You don't need the DataInputStream so remove it. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html#!/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Comment: I want to give the program 2 substring positions and it returns me the string from the text file.

Comment: Do you want to output a specific line? Or may the position be something else than a line number?

Comment: No i dont want to output a specific line. For e.g
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           String str = "University";
    System.out.println(str.substring(4,7));
            }   
      }
The output is "ers"

My program should take the 2 positions and display the string in the file having that position. If i put (str.substring(4,7)); The result should be "wo
th" according to the text file.

Comment: Edit your question to add clear info on what you expect and what your exact problem is. Be as narrow as possible

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 2):

If you know the *byte* offsets within the file that you are interested in then it's straightforward:

```
RandomAccessFile raFile = new RandomAccessFile("textfile.txt", "r");
raFile.seek(startOffset);
byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
raFile.readFully(bytes);
raFile.close();
String str = new String(bytes, "Windows-1252"); // or whatever encoding
```

But for this to work you have to use byte offsets, not character offsets - if the file is encoded in a variable-width encoding such as UTF-8 then there's no way to seek directly to the nth *character*, you have to start at the top of the file and read and discard the first n-1 characters.

Comment: or just use 'InputStream.skip(numberOfBytes)'

Comment: @JayC667 and double-check the return value to ensure that it really did skip the number of bytes you asked it to - skip is allowed to skip fewer than `numberOfBytes`.

Answer (score 0):

look for `\r\n` (linebreaks) in your text file. This way you should be able to count the rows containing your string.

your file in reality looks like this

```
one\r\n
two\r\n
three\r\n
four\r\n
```

Comment: in this way am able to do it.but i want to access lets say the sting " three " in the file by its 2 positions the start and end position. Am not directly searching for the string.

Comment: so your position is row and lineStartIndex and lineEndIndex?

Comment: better: start = row + lineStartIndex and end = row + lineEndIndex. care that it doesn't become negative!

Comment: Newlines are encoded in different ways on different platforms. `\r\n` is specific to Windows and x86 BIOS mode strings, `\n` is used n Unix-like OSes and `\r` on Macs (not sure if the latter is still the case with OS X which is BSD-based). Therefore you shouldn't rely on files containing `\r\n` for linefeeds.

Comment: entirely true, but it seems to me that there are more basic things to get aware of first (for now at least).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156325/how-to-get-a-string-from-a-java-file-by-using-only-start-and-end-position). The code I posted there works on the byte level, so it may not work for you. Another option is to use the BufferedReader and just read a single character in a loop like this:

```
String getString(String fileName, int start, int end) throws IOException {
    int len = end - start;
    if (len <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Length of string to output is zero or negative.");
    }

    char[] buffer = new char[len];
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    for (int i = 0; i < start; i++) {
        reader.read(); // Ignore the result
    }

    reader.read(buffer, 0, len);
    return new String(buffer);
}
```