# Java Random File Access: Get byte offset of line start

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, randomaccessfile

I need to randomly access specific records in a text (ASCII) file and then read from there until a specific "stop sequence" (record delimiter) is found. The file contains multi-line records and each record is separated by the delimiter. Each record also takes a different amount of lines! This is a commonly known file format in the specific area of expertise and can not be changed.

I want to index the file so I can quickly jump to a requested record.

In similar questions like

[How to Access string in file by position in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156314/how-to-access-string-in-file-by-position-in-java)

and links in it, answer always reference the `seek()` method of various classes like `RandomAccessFile`. I know about that!

The issue I have is how to get the offset needed for seek! (indexing the file)

`BufferedReader` does not have a `getFilePointer()` method or any other to get the current byte offset from start of file. `RandomAccessFile` has a `readLine()` method but it's performance is beyond terrible. It's not usable at all for my case.

I would need to read the file line by line and each time the record delimiter is found I need to get the byte offset. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is it an option to split the file into records and store the records in a database?  Maybe some flavor of NoSQL?

Comment: Cache the indices: either in memory, in some "index holder" object; or on some persistent storage, like a database, a separate file or a header; depending on what you need this for.

Comment: @ViktorSeifert should be a simple solution as in standalone

Comment: @blgt index is cached in memory but adding support for saving it and restoring is planned But the issue is to get somewhat acceptable performance in building it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of further googling, trial and error and more I came up with a solution that simply wraps `RandomAccessFile` and exposes all methods. The `readLine()` method however was much improved by talking the one from `BufferedReader` with minor adjustments. Performance is now identical to it.

This so called class `OptimizedRandomAccessFile` buffers readLine() calls as long as no other methods requiring or affecting the position in the file are called. eg in:

```
OptimizedRandomAccessFile raf = new OptimizedRandomAccessFile(filePath, "r");
String line = raf.readLine();
int nextByte = raf.read();
```

`nextByte` will contain the first byte of the next line in the file.

The full code can be found on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/kienerj/io).

Answer (score 2):

You can try to subclass the `BufferedReader` class to remember the read position. But you won't have the seek functionality.

As you mentioned a record can be multi-line, but all the records are separated by a stop sequence. Given this you can use `RandomAccessFile` like this:

1. have a byte buffer `byte b[]` of let's say 8k in size (this is for performance reasons)
2. read 8k from the file in this buffer and try to find the delimiter, if not found, read another block of 8k, but previously append the data to some `StringBuilder` or other structure.
3. when you found the delimiter the position of the delimiter is given by the number of bytes processed since the last delimiter found (you need to do some simple math).

The tricky part will be if the record delimiter is longer that 1 char, but that should be a big problem.

Comment: the delimiter is 4 chars. And it could theoretically (but very unlikely and also dumb) appear within a record, meaning to be 100% sure it must be the 4 chars on a separate line.

Comment: so basically your delimiter is `newline + your 4 characters`. should not be a problem. each time a record is greater than 8k and appended already part of them to the `StringBuilder` I mentioned at step #2, you can try to see if that `StringBuilder` ends with the start of the delimiter and the newly read data starts with the rest of the delimiter. This could be a few lines of code method. Let me know if this was clear.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following sequence of java.io decorators:

```
   InputStreamReader    <-- reader, the top reader
   CountingInputStream  <-- cis, stores the position (from Google Guava)
   BufferedInputStream  <-- speeds up file reading
   FileInputStream
```

Then you read from this top reader by implementing a `readLine()` method which reads chars one by one until a line separator. I would not use BufferedReader as it would spoil the current position by reading a full fixed-sized buffer.

So if I get the problem right, the algorithm is as simple as

1. `long lineStartPosition = cis.getCount();`
2. `String s = readLine(reader);`
3. `if(s.equals(DELIMITER)) { storeToIndex(lineStartPosition, recordData); }`

Comment: InputStreamReader does buffer in some conditions - "To enable the efficient conversion of bytes to characters, more bytes may be read ahead from the underlying stream than are necessary to satisfy the current read operation."

Answer (score 0):

You can read all the data file and record where the delimiter is found and save this metadata in a different file. Now you can use the metadata to navigate through the file (jump from one delimiter to the other). Each time the data file gets modified, you will have to rescan it and regenerate the metadata.