# How to really find the position of a string in a file in java?

Tags: java, string, stream

There's an immense amount of forum posts, blog entries and questions in Q&As (including this site[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm)) answering this question wrongly and showing an alarming misunderstanding of what reading files means for applications. Reading a file into memory and operating on it is not a suitable solution for arbitrary large files (and it lies in the nature of file to be arbitrary large).

So now I'm looking for a "real" solution to *search a string in a file and retrieve its position counted from the beginning of the stream*. To make things clear and not produce the 19382th useless answer:

- A file is a file. They can be some TB large if not specified contrarily. That implies that reading a file into memory will potentially crash my application and/or cause downtime of my service if the file size isn't validated. Reading files of limited size is not(!) part of my question[2].
- A string is a string. They can be of arbitrary length, especially larger than the buffer the file content is read into during stream processing (not larger than memory, though)!

AFAIK there's no class in the Java 7 JDK, especially *not* `java.util.Scanner` which doesn't retrieve the position of the results and requires the position to be found with `java.lang.String.indexOf` which requires the input to be in memory! There definitely have to be some streaming libraries for gene substring search used in bioinformatics which have such search already implemented.

Not even [Wikipedia's article on string search algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) mentiones or links stream-based processing!

**EDIT 1:** I gave up and used python with the `bitstring` module (available with `pip`). It reaches read troughput of 170MB/s (with is the read maximum of the OS) and is well tested; got my script working with 5 lines of code, i.e. exactly what I'm looking for! I'm still interested in (real) solutions for java, though.

---

[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) [How to Access string in file by position in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156314/how-to-access-string-in-file-by-position-in-java)

[2] And also not of the many questions out there which are answered wrongly in my POV (and therefore are actually wrong questions).

Comment: There's `FileInputStream`. Is that not streamy enough for you? (Note: This answer is just as generic as your question)

Comment: @Kayaman No, because I have to implement the search exceeding the buffer size myself and I fear to reinvent the wheel at this point. For example if my buffer for reading from (any) `InputStream` is 1024 bytes and my search string 5849 bytes and I find a match from the 314th byte in the 7th read with `InputStream.read(byte[])` then I still have a lot to program and especially test...

Comment: It doesn't matter how long your search string is, you'll still look for the first byte before checking if the rest match. This is hardly a complicated problem. I would of course suggest a `BufferedInputStream`, so you can read a byte at a time at will.

Answer (score 0):

You could [adapt a DataFetcher and a FetcherListener](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java) to read byte[] chunks from your file until you find the string that you are looking for. The adaptation you'd need to make is to take care of the case where your search string occurs in between reads. So you'd need to store the last searchstring.length - 1 bytes of each read to append to the next read's data

Comment: I didn't find the search functionality in there. How does it sparse me e.g. to implement the search for the example I gave in the 2nd comment to the question? `FetchListener` only provides me a `byte[]` with the start and end position, but I have to implement the search myself, right?

Answer (score 0):

Java VTD-XML provides some code maintaning a byte offset after each call to the getChar() method of its IReader implementations.

IReader implementations for various caracter encodings are available inside VTDGen.java and VTDGenHuge.java

IReader implementations are provided for the following encodings

ASCII;
ISO_8859_1
ISO_8859_10
ISO_8859_11
ISO_8859_12
ISO_8859_13
ISO_8859_14
ISO_8859_15
ISO_8859_16
ISO_8859_2
ISO_8859_3
ISO_8859_4
ISO_8859_5
ISO_8859_6
ISO_8859_7
ISO_8859_8
ISO_8859_9
UTF_16BE
UTF_16LE
UTF8;
WIN_1250
WIN_1251
WIN_1252
WIN_1253
WIN_1254
WIN_1255
WIN_1256
WIN_1257
WIN_1258
Updating IReader with a getCharOffset() method and implementing it by adding a charCount member along to the offset member of the VTDGen and VTDGenHuge classes and by incrementing it upon each getChar() and skipChar() call of each IReader implementation should be a solution.